# How to change the bash shell working directory by the ruby?

Tags: ruby, shell

When we run this ruby code:

`IO.popen('cd ~/Desktop/workDir')`

It will create sub shell to run this cmd, and the working directory will changed in the sub shell,but the parent shell.

So, If I want to change the parentShell's working directory by ruby, how can I do this?

Comment: Not sure if this is what you want. But to change a directory use `Dir.chdir('/home')` etc.

Comment: In the same way，It is only change the sub shell's dir.

Comment: A child process can not alter the environment of the parent. You will have to have the child process print out commands that the parent shell can `source`/`eval` -> `bash$ source "$(/path/to/change_dir_script.rb)"` and the ruby script does `puts "cd #{ENV['HOME']}/Desktop/workDir"`

Comment: Thanks for your answer first, It seems as if there is no way to do this by ruby code.